# Maximum input frequency of 74HC Logic gates

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, high-speed

I have a clock that is running at 25.175MHz I want to run that signal through some basic logic gates from the 74HC series. 
I have looked on the datasheet for the 74HC08 (AND Gate), I can't seem to find any information about the maximum frequency i can run through these gates.

Does anyone know how to find this information, hopefully I am not being too stupid and it's on the datasheet. I have checked 3 times now!

So my question is: What is the maximum input frequency of the 74HC Logic gates?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not in the datasheet, it's in the [HCMOS user guide](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/logic/pdf/user.guide.hcmos.pdf), as it concerns all HCMOS components.

On page 4:

> D-Flip-Flop: 30 MHz minimum, 55 MHz typical
>   Counter: 25 MHz minimum, 45 MHz typical

For gates this will probably be in the same ballpark, since for those only rise and fall times are relevant, and not propagation delay.

If you want something faster, then NXP's Advanced Ultra-low Power series (AUP) [quotes](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74AUP2G80.pdf) frequencies up to 619 MHz.

Comment: I think a more "compatible" family would be the AHC (three times the speed and almost the same supply voltage).

Answer (score 3):

The information you need is in the datasheet, but not in the format you expect. The [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT08.pdf) shows the Phl and Plh maximum propagation delays, which are 18 ns for the HC chip at 4.5V. Worst worst case you must assue that each edge of your input signal can be delayed 0..18ns. If Murphy visits he will delay each rising edge by 18 ns, and each falling edge by 0 ns. That means that an 18ns pulse (half the periode of a symmetrical 1/36ns = 28 Mhz signal) will disappear completely, and lower frequency signals will be distorted with the same amount (edges can drift 0..18 ns).

Note that this is worst worst case, in practice the delays of rising and falling edges will differ less. But I would not bet on a 18ns input pulse appearing at the output as 18 ns. It might, but it might also be 36 ns, or disappear completely. Or anyting inbetween.

Comment: I agree with the principle of your calculation, but I'm not sure you can apply it here like that. What if the duty cycle is 40 % instead of 50 %? Also, in my experience Tphl and Tplh are almost the same, so this would give you an infinite maximum frequency?

Comment: The maximum frequency that can be reproduced at all at the output is limited by the maximum delay: when the falling edge arrives a the input before the gate has switched fully, all bets are off. The difference between the input waveform and the output waveform (for instance the duty cycle) is affected by the uncertainty in the difference of the Phl and the Plh.

Answer (score 0):

I am switching 40MHz VGA signals with a 74HC157.
No issues. Real hardware on a breadboard.

Comment: HC speed differ by a factor > 5 from 2 V to 6 V supply: Please state the voltage used.

Comment: @RadicalBrad Please expand this answer.